# New version of gapi class

Tags: php, api

I've used gapi class(version 1.3.) for working with google analytics in my project. But recently it stopped working. For example, I can't retrieve projects of ga account.
I suppose this happened because of updates in google analytics.
Maybe somewhere a new version of gapi class exists ? Any thoughts?

Comment: No, I am using 1.3 and it works fine. And as far as I know 1.3 is the latest. http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: method requestAccountData() doesn't work...

Comment: $response = $this->httpRequest(Google_Api::account_data_url, array('start-index' => $start_index, 'max-results' => $max_results), null, $this->generateAuthHeader());
And after it $response['code']=404

Comment: I get this error too with requestAccountData method (I never required to use this method)

Answer (score 0):

I found this class http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/analytics/simple.php to resolve problem. But it has absolutely different idea as compared with Gapi class version 1.3

Maybe somebody know better solution...